# TypeError: Merge can only be called on a list of tensors, not a single tensor in keras

Tags: python, keras, merge, lstm, bidirectional

I am using version 1.15.5 tensorflow and version 1.2.2 cross. I can implement other models, but given the load_weight in the DanQ article, I can't change the code much.

DanQ---> 1: https://github.com/uci-cbcl/DanQ

**Code:**

```
model1 = Sequential()
model1.add(LSTM(input_dim=320, output_dim=320, return_sequences=True))
model2 = Sequential()
model2.add(LSTM(input_dim=320, output_dim=320, return_sequences=True))
merged = Merge([model1, model2], mode='sum')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution1D(320, border_mode='valid',filter_length=26, activation="relu", subsample_length=1,input_shape=(1000,4)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_length=13, stride=13))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))

model.add(merged)

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Flatten())

model.add(Dense(input_dim=75*640, output_dim=925))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(input_dim=925, output_dim=919))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
```

[Error of this code:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/brxTv.jpg)

Comment: are you sure, you're not looking for concatenate? https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate

Comment: I use Cross 1.2.2 and Tensorflow 1.15.5, so I use merge. Concatinate is used in Flow Tensor 2.x and Cross 2.x.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer.
Because I had to use the low cross version. But because I do not have access to the lower version of the cross, I updated my layers using the latest cross.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).